# Perform logic using a CTE instead of loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Suppose I have a table

```
Declare @table table
               ( 
                   id int,
                   month_col varchar(10),
                   present_col bit, 
                   absent_col bit,
                   leave_col bit
               );

insert into @table
values (1, 'Jan', 1, 0, 0),
       (2, 'Jan', 1, 0, 0),
       (3, 'Jan', 0, 1, 0),
       (4, 'Jan', 1, 0, 0),
       (5, 'Jan', 0, 1, 0),
       (6, 'Jan', 1, 0, 0),
       (7, 'Jan', 1, 0, 0);
```

While updating some rows, I need to check all previous rows leave col to take decision for current row, this need to be done for all rows, I had achieve this with while loop like this

```
while(for all rows)
begin
    update @table
    set l = mylogic_function((select count(leave_col) 
                              from @table 
                              where id<currentrow.ID)) 
    where id = currentrow.ID
end
```

but I want to do this logic by using a CTE.

Comment: but one think keep in mind, when ever row gets update, the result of it will be included in next row updation

Comment: simple to understand: when a row is updating with record of last those rows which is updated recently the same query.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Desired results would also help.  I don't understand the logic you want to implement.  What does `mylogic_function()` do?

Comment: @GordonLinoff i am using sql server 2008, well mylogic_function() is checking leave records from other source, and take decision by using last previous leave_col data, but this column must have latest value.

Comment: i want set base approach to update each row of column but those rows which has been updated should give latest value to next row to take decision, means recursively i am fetching all rows, and updating each single handed, to get last updation effect on next row update

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "while updating rows".  There might be a window function using rank, dense rank, or count distinct on an ordered query . . ??  Maybe show us input and expected output.

Comment: @QuaperClient, What is your end expected result should look alike.

Comment: @QuaperClient `i am using sql server 2008` add the proper tag then - that's significant. SQL Server 2008 is out of support and doesn't use the windowing functions *all* supported versions provide. In fact, it's past time this was upgraded to a modern SQL Server version

Comment: @QuaperClient have you tried running that statement *without* the loop and the `WHERE` clause? The UPDATE query itself will generate a running count of rows, essentially a row number

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your function does so, for my example I created a function that takes an input and returns a 1 when that number is divisible by three. Obviously you can change the logic to what you need.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.someFunction(@x INT) RETURNS BIT AS BEGIN RETURN (SIGN(@x%3)-1) END;
```

It's good that you don't want to do this using a loop BUT a solution that uses a ***recursive*** CTE (if that's what you are looking for) will likely perform poorly and will be overly complicated for what you are trying to do. Set-based is always the way to go.

To get a count of all rows before your "current" row you could simply use this syntax:

```
COUNT(t.leave_col) OVER (ORDER BY t.Id)
```

This will return the same thing as above but will be faster:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.Id)
```

This query will do what you're looking for and will be faster than using a loop or *recursive* CTE:

```
-- Sample data
Declare @table table(id int,month_col varchar(10),present_col bit, absent_col bit,leave_col bit);
insert into @table values
(1,'Jan',1,0,0),
(5,'Jan',1,0,0),
(13,'Jan',0,1,0),
(14,'Jan',1,0,0),
(25,'Jan',0,1,0),
(26,'Jan',1,0,0),
(37,'Jan',1,0,0);

-- Solution
WITH Prep(leave_col_count, leave_col) AS 
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.Id), t.leave_col
  FROM   @table AS t
)
UPDATE Prep 
SET    leave_col = dbo.someFunction(Prep.leave_col_count)
FROM   Prep;
```